# Connect Wordpress Vagrant VM to MySQL Vagrant VM

Tags: wordpress, vagrant, virtual-machine

First of, I am pretty new to Vagrant. I have two Vagrant VMs to set up a Wordpress. This is my Vagrantfile:

Note: The synced folder "wordpress" in `web1` contains the official files of the latest Wordpress files downloadable from their page using `wget http://wordpress.org/latest.zip` and decompressing it afterwards.

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
    config.vm.box = "generic/ubuntu2010"

    config.vm.define :web1 do |web1|
        web1.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
            vb.name = "web1"
            vb.memory = "1024"
        end
    web1.vm.hostname = "web1"
    web1.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 1234
    web1.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.100.101", virtualbox__intnet: true
    web1.vm.synced_folder "wordpress", "/var/www/html"
    web1.vm.provision :shell, inline: <<-SHELL
        apt-get update
        apt-get install -y apache2 php php-mysql
    SHELL
    end

    config.vm.define :db do |db|
        db.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
            vb.name = "db"
            vb.memory = "1024"
        end
    db.vm.hostname = "db"
    db.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.100.105", virtualbox__intnet: true
    db.vm.provision :shell, inline: <<-SHELL
        apt-get update
        apt-get install -y mysql-server
        mysql -u root -e "CREATE DATABASE wordpress;"
        mysql -u root -e "CREATE USER 'wp_user'@'192.168.100.105' IDENTIFIED BY 'wp_pass';"
        mysql -u root -e "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON wordpress.* TO 'wp_user'@'192.168.100.105';"
    SHELL
    end
end
```

When I go to `localhost:1234` and fill up the form with the DB data, I get "Error establishing a database connection". I have tried a bunch of things and haven't got any further. How can I fix this?

Thank you

Comment: hey, can u ssh into web1 and check connectivity from there, ping db ip make sure it works, and try connect to mysql. check the connection setting for the database from wordpress and make sure you can connect using the same from web1 CLI

Comment: I can ping db from web1 succesfully, but I don't know how to check the connection setting that you're talking about?

Comment: it should be in your wordpress configuration, check the file wp-config.php if you have, you should see the DB_HOST etc, make sure it is not set with localhost

Comment: I have changed that too, and I still get the same error.